# How to list folders in another apps directory?

Tags: java, android

Just to clarify, this is on a rooted device. Here is my code

```
    try {
        Process p;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "\\data\\data\\com.another.app\\files"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would expect p to be the output of the shell command but it never gets assigned a value.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "/" instead of "\"? This is not Windows. =)

Also, try using a terminal on the device to execute that same ls (with /, though) to check if the path really exists.